# How to reference function defined in __init__ super class

Tags: python, inheritance, init

I have a helper function (`def convert(dictionary`)  inside my `__init__` class to assist with configuration setup.  The definition is as follows:

```
class Configuration:

    def __init__(self, config_file=None, config=None):

        if config_file is not None:
            with open(config_file) as in_file:
                self._config = yaml.load(in_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        elif config is not None:
            self._config = config
        else:
            raise ValueError("Could not create configuration. Must pass either location of config file or valid "
                             "config.")

        def convert(dictionary):
            return namedtuple('Config', dictionary.keys())(**dictionary)
```

This allows me to make a call within `__init__` as follows:

```
        self.input = convert(self._config["input"])
        self.output = convert(self._config["output"])
        self.build = convert(self._config["build_catalog"])
```

Since I have more than one configs to set up I want to inherit from his class as follows:

```
class BuildConfiguration(Configuration):

    def __init__(self, config_file=None, config=None):

        super().__init__(config_file, config)

        self.input = convert(self._config["input"])
        self.output = convert(self._config["output"])
        self.build = convert(self._config["build_catalog"])
```

I however do not gain access to `convert` from the parent class.  I have also tried this:

`self.input = super().__init__.convert(self._config["input"])`

This also seems to not work.

So the question is how do I get access to a function defined in `super().__init__` from child classes?

Comment: tl;dr; **You can't**. If you want to access that, define them outside of `__init__` by making a method or gloably in the module namespace, nesting functions like that is never a good thing to do(unless you really have to). Since the `convert` function don't have any relation with the class `Configuration`, just make it a normal `function` in the `module`

Comment: Logically speaking, `def convert` is only created when calling `__init__`, it only exists within its scope, and it's discarded when `__init__` ends. So no, it doesn't exist outside of it.

Comment: Also, you create another `namedtuple` class *on each invocation* of the function. This entire setup is just bad. Define the `namedtuple` class outside, so you only create *one of the* and define that helper function in the global scope or perhaps as a method.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, **if** you are returning it, it is fine. hey, that's what we do for `decorators`. But in this case, it makes no sense, yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A new function is created on each invocation of `__init__` and it is discarded, *it doesn't exist outside the function*. Note, this also applies to the class being created by `namedtuple('Config', dictionary.keys())(**dictionary)`. It really isn't good to keep creating all these unnecessary classes, which totally defeats the purpose of `namedtuple` which is for creating memory-efficient record-types. Here, each instance has it's own class!

Here is how you should define this:

```
Config = namedtuple('Config', "foo bar baz")

def convert(dictionary): # is this really necessary?
    return Config(**dictionary) 

class Configuration:

    def __init__(self, config_file=None, config=None):

        if config_file is not None:
            with open(config_file) as in_file:
                self._config = yaml.load(in_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        elif config is not None:
            self._config = config
        else:
            raise ValueError("Could not create configuration. Must pass either location of config file or valid "
                             "config.")

        self.input = convert(self._config["input"])
        self.output = convert(self._config["output"])
        self.build = convert(self._config["build_catalog"])
```

Although at this point, it seems cleaner to just use

```
Config(**self._config["input"])
```

etc instead and ditch the helper `convert`.

Comment: Yep, happy with this last approach.  Thanks.